# Bootstrap: display different content on the same iframe

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, iframe

I have two iframes, iframe1 for buttons and iframe2 will be the space where content will be displayed when a button is clicked. I want different content to be displayed in iframe2 when each button is clicked but i can't have the content in iframe2 to be replaced by the content (or the .html file) relative to the click of a button. I have included sample code.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sample</title>


</head>
<body>
<iframe id="iframe1" src="index2.html" name="iframe1" height="650" width="30%"></iframe>
<iframe id="iframe2"  name="iframe1" height="650" width="60%"></iframe>


</body>
</html>
```

- index2.html = contents of iframe1 (this holds the buttons)

  ```
    <div class="dropdown clearfix">
      <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown1
      <span class="caret"></span></button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a class="button" src="index2.html" onclick="$('#iframe2')" href="#">HTML</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">python</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">java</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  ```
- cssc.html = sample content (this should appear in iframe2 when i click CSS from the dropdown menu)

  sample content for dropdown menu element CSS- this content should appear in iframe2
- htmlc.html = this content should replace any content in iframe2 when HTML is clicked from the dropdown

  ## sample content for dropdown menu element HTML- this content should appear in iframe2